# Integrating Angular 2 with Sails.js

Tags: typescript, sails.js, angular

I want Integrate sails with angular 2 ,also I want to add this project typescripts How i configure this I'm new for that filed

I create sails app like this,

```
sails new myApp
```

How I add this my project?

Comment: there are I try http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html but i got error "node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): error TS2661: Cannot re-export name that is not defined in the module."

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score -2):

Thereis one solution which comes from this URL : http://sharpten.com/blog/2016/02/02/integrating-angular-2-with-sails-js.html

This tutorial doesn't work anymore since it askes npm to install v2.0.0 beta2 of angular and the lastest version of Typescript (currently 1.8). However, TS 1.8 requires using angular2 beta7 or higher (but lower version works perfectly fine with TS 1.7.5) that is why you have this error message :

"node_modules/angular2/src/facade/promise.d.ts(1,10): error TS2661: Cannot re-export name that is not defined in the module."

Source 1 : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6795

Source 2 : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6468

So here how I did it :

First of all you have to install globally Typescript :

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Then add the dependencies in your package.json, this is what you should have :

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "a Sails application",
  "keywords": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "2.3.4",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "0.13.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jst": "0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.3",
    "grunt-sails-linker": "~0.10.1",
    "grunt-sync": "0.2.4",
    "include-all": "~0.1.6",
    "rc": "1.0.1",
    "sails": "~0.12.1",
    "sails-disk": "~0.10.9",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.9",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "zone.js": "0.5.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.7",
    "typings":"^0.7.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "node debug app.js",
    "start": "concurrently  \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"node app.js\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
   "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
   "lite": "lite-server",
   "typings": "typings",
   "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/root/pietate.git"
  },
  "author": "root",
  "license": ""
}
```

> Notice that thanks to the "start" ligne into "scripts" we will start
>   the compiler, the server and the sails server at once by using :
>
> ```
> npm start
> ```

Install the lastest version of the dependencies with :

```
npm update --save
```

Then add the following code into a new tsconfig.json file, this file contains the configuration for Typescript and should be placed in your sails application root.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

According to angular.io :

> Many JavaScript libraries extend the JavaScript environment with
>   features and syntax that the TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize
>   natively. We teach it about these capabilities with TypeScript type
>   definition files — d.ts files — which we identify in a typings.json
>   file

So we need to add a typings.json file on our application root:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#4de74cb527395c13ba20b438c3a7a419ad931f1c",
    "jasmine": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#d594ef506d1efe2fea15f8f39099d19b39436b71"
  }
}
```

Now, let's assume you uses EJS as template engine, add this to your layout.ejs :

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script>
System.config({
          map: {
              rxjs: 'node_modules/rxjs' // added this map section
          },
          packages: {
              app: {
                  format: 'register',
                  defaultExtension: 'js'
              },
              'rxjs': {defaultExtension: 'js'} // and added this to packages
          }
      });
System.import('/app/main')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

This code above loads Angular 2 and ES6 modules. The /app/main.ts is not created yet (we'll do it later), it is the entry script for Angular 2. However, if you try to start the server with "sails lift" you may notice  404 errors for the scripts we just added.

By default sails doesn't have a static access entry to the folder /node_modules. Add this to a new file express.js in config the config folder (config/express.js):

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports.http = {
customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use('/node_modules', express.static(process.cwd() + '/node_modules'));
   }
};
```

This express.js file works as a middleware to give express access to /node_modules.

Here are two Typescript codes which will be compiled, create them into a new folder assets/app/.

assets/app/main.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts" />

import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

We use a reference because we excluded /node_modules from compilation.

```
assets/app/app.components.ts :

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Now you can use :

npm start

Take a look at : localhost:1337 , you should see a  My First Angular 2 App

I hope you understood everything.

Alix

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).